# Annotating React Navigation with TypeScript

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

The current structure of my application has a stack navigator nested inside a tab navigator. I'm following [React Navigation guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) on how to annotate the props.

1. Helper type

```js
**
 * Tabs in the app
 */
export type TabParamList = {
  ChatTab: undefined;
  HomeTab: undefined;
  CalendarTab: undefined;
};

/**
 * Screens inside home tab
 */
export type HomeStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
};

/**
 * Screens inside chat tab
 */
export type ChatStackParamList = {
  Chat: undefined;
  Voice: undefined;
};

/**
 * Screens inside authentication
 */
export type AuthenticationStackParamList = {
  Welcome: undefined;
  Login: undefined;
  Signup: undefined;
};

export type ComposeNavigator<
  T extends keyof TabParamList,
  P extends ParamListBase,
  S extends keyof P
> = CompositeScreenProps<
  BottomTabScreenProps<TabParamList, T>,
  StackScreenProps<P, S>
>;
```

2. Usage

```js
type NavigatorProps = ComposeNavigator<"ChatTab", ChatStackParamList, "Voice">;
type Props = NavigatorProps;

const VoiceScreen = ({ navigation }: Props) => {
 return <></>
}
```

3. I'm now running into type errors for createStackNavigation. Following the compiler error, I extended ComposeNavigator to have `{children?: React.ReactNode}` but it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```js
const ChatNavigator = () => {
  const { screenOptions } = useDefaultHeaderStyle();

  /** @TODO component prop has type error */
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Chat" screenOptions={screenOptions}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Chat" component={ChatScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Voice" component={VoiceScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

4. Dependencies

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.3",
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: I've included the original code, sorry for that!